# How do I see output of SQL query in node-sqlite3?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I read all the [documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) and this seemingly simple operation seems completely ignored throughout the entire README.

Currently, I am trying to run a SELECT query and console.log the results, but it is simply returning a database object. How do I view the results from my query in Node console?

```
exports.runDB = function() {
  db.serialize(function() {
    console.log(db.run('SELECT * FROM archive'));
  });
db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`run` does not have retrieval capabilities. You need to use `all`, `each`, or `get`

[According to the documentation for all](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API):

> Note that it first retrieves all result rows and stores them in
>   memory. For queries that have potentially large result sets, use the
>   Database#each function to retrieve all rows or Database#prepare
>   followed by multiple Statement#get calls to retrieve a previously
>   unknown amount of rows.

As an illistration:

```
db.all('SELECT url, rowid FROM archive', function(err, table) {
  console.log(table);
});
```

That will return all entries in the `archive` table as an array of objects.